# Looking for a black/white only terminal emulator on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, color

My original question on Stack Overflow [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398947/looking-for-a-vt100-black-white-terminal-emulator). Basically, I ssh into my linux work station from my Mac and I would like to test my program (that runs on the linux machine) if color output is not supported on my terminal emulator. Currently I am using Terminal.app and I've tried setting Preferences > Settings > Advanced > Declare terminal as different terminal types but all of them still seem to print colors.

Does anyone know a black/white only terminal emulator for Mac? Is there a way to completely turn off colors on a terminal?

Answer (score 2):

I use [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/), which allows you to set styles, including black and white.

Answer (score -1):

[Here's a black and white terminal for Terminal.app](http://georgegarside.com/o/se/blackandwhite.terminal) (download linked file and remove txt).
This maps all the colours in Terminal to be black and white, therefore disabling colour.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ANSIBlueColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIBrightBlackColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIBrightBlueColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIBrightCyanColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIBrightGreenColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIBrightMagentaColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIBrightRedColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIBrightWhiteColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIBrightYellowColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSICyanColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIGreenColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIMagentaColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIRedColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIWhiteColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ANSIYellowColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OV05TV2hpdGVcTlNDb2xvclNwYWNlViRjbGFzc0Iw
    ABADgALSEBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3Rf
    EA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSFBdZGdpa3B7hIyPmKqt
    sgAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0
    </data>
    <key>ProfileCurrentVersion</key>
    <real>2.04</real>
    <key>SelectionColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OVU5TUkdCXE5TQ29sb3JTcGFjZVYkY2xhc3NGMSAx
    IDEAEAGAAtIQERITWiRjbGFzc25hbWVYJGNsYXNzZXNXTlNDb2xvcqISFFhOU09iamVj
    dF8QD05TS2V5ZWRBcmNoaXZlctEXGFRyb290gAEIERojLTI3O0FITltiaWttcn2GjpGa
    rK+0AAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALY=
    </data>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Black &amp; White</string>
    <key>type</key>
    <string>Window Settings</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```